# Show validation messages on GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation

We have a possibility that data loaded from a GET operation could be invalid for posting, and would like to be able to display the validation messages when the data is first loaded. The validation all takes place on server side using ValidationAttributes.

How can I force the validation summary to be displayed when the data is first loaded? I am guessing that I need to force errors into ModelState somehow, but I first need to get them out of the model class.

Comment: Did you read this? http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx You can run validation and then fill ModelState with values.

Comment: That is just the sort of thing I was looking for, @LukLed, thanks...trying it out now.

Comment: I tried that, @LukLed, but could not force the validations to take place consistently. As long as they were based on the canned attributes from DataAnnotation, they would fire, but the custom ones we'd added did not...no idea why and I took another approach, see below.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a validation method for the model class which adds errors to the ModelState. Then I created and added a custom ModelValidator and AssociatedValidatorProvider 
for calling it during the normal validation that takes place during form binding. That way the controller actions that don't bind to the Model class directly can still have a call to the model's .Validate(ModelState) method to fake a validation. This approach works well for server-side-only validation.

UserInfo **Model class**:

```
private IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
{
    List<RuleViolation> violationList = new List<RuleViolation>();

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName)) 
        violationList.Add(new RuleViolation("First Name is required.", FirstName"));

    return violationList;
}

public void Validate(System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
{
    foreach (RuleViolation violation in GetRuleViolations())
   {
        ModelState.AddModelError(violation.PropertyName, violation.ErrorMessage);
   }
}
```

This is how it can be used directly from a **controller action.** In this action the Model class object is returned as part of the UserSearch model.

```
public ActionResult Search(UserSearch model)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Search();
        if (model.UserInfo != null )
        {
            model.UserInfo.Validate(ModelState);
        }
    }...
```

That is all I had to do for the particular use case I was working on. But I went ahead and completed the work to do "normal" validation on a postback: created a simple ModelValidator, with the Validate override looking like this. If you followed the above pattern in all of your Model classes you could probably reusue this for them, too.

```
public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
{
    var results = new List<ModelValidationResult>();
    if (Metadata.Model != null)
    {
        UserInfoViewModel uinfo = Metadata.Model as UserInfoViewModel;
        foreach (var violation in uinfo.GetRuleViolations())
        {
            results.Add(new ModelValidationResult
                {
                    MemberName = violation.PropertyName,
                    Message = violation.ErrorMessage
                });
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Finally, extend AssociatedValidationProvider to return this ModelValidator and add it to the ModelValidationProviders collection in Application_Start. There is a writeup of this at http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx#s2-validation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understand what you need, but here is it...

run validation to display the validation summary when the form is loaded, using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#FormId').valid(); 
});
```